# How to implement sorting and pagination to viewchildren

Tags: angular

We know it is easy to do sorting and pagination in angular(only consider sorting in client end). refer to : https://stackblitz.com/angular/dnblbyvggqyj?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts.
But how to integrate sorting and pagination for several seperate tables(same data structure for these tables).

For my understanding, in order to do this, we need serveral **viewChild**(the number of viewchild equals to the number of table). Also we need to initialize serveral **MatTableDataSource** objects. We can put it in a hashmap Like:

```
{table1Tittle: new MatTableDataSource<Object>(), table2Tittle: new MatTableDataSource<Object>(), ...., };
```

But the thing is we don't know the number of table before we get the data. How should we decorate the viewchild and let the number of viewchild to be same as the number of table.

Comment: While I'm sure you could get this to work, would it be possible to instead create a child component that has each mat-table in it with it's own sort and pagination?  So instead of building a bunch of tables in your top level component you would just ngFor through your data set and create a bunch of child components that each have their own sort and pagination view children.